# Google Sheets onEdit events not working

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I registered my trigger on Edit->Current Project's Trigger and then made this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().toast(e.value);
}
```

I also tried it without registering the trigger in case there's some odd collision thing.  Is there something else I need to do to trigger the function?

Comment: Have you authorized the script? You generally need to force a permissions dialog to pop up before your triggers will run. Also, do not name installed triggers with reserved names - `onEdit` is reserved for a simple trigger, and will always attempt to run when a user edits cells, even if the function calls services that need authorization. It will generate errors when it encounters those lines.

Comment: Oh yes, I bet I have to run a fake function just to see if the permission thing will come up. I'll try tomorrow.  Many other times I do the event at the end for the menu and have debugged already. This was just throw away code so I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to do authorization like [tehhowch](/users/9337071/tehhowch)'s [comment](/questions/50728510/google-sheets-onedit-events-not-working/50729174#comment88465286_50728510) suggests, or your function has an error. If it has an error and it won't pop up and notify you, try to run the function manually with the debugger and be sure your script is correct.

Comment: It is nice that you are trying to help, but much better is too leave a comment. Please earn some reputation for a next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bunch of [reserved simple trigger functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) that you **should not use as variable name** as they're integral in Apps Script:

> - **onOpen(e)** runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that he or she has permission to edit.
> - **onEdit(e)** runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.
> - **onInstall(e)** runs when a user installs an add-on.
> - **doGet(e)** runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends an HTTP GET request to a web app.
> - **doPost(e)** runs when a program sends an HTTP POST request to a web app.

Comment: You can absolutely use them (that's why they exist), you just need to use them as they are intended - "no authorization required" things. Installable triggers are for the similar situations needing authorization.

Answer (score 0):

editing my answer in case I didnt understand what your problem was. I ended up having another issue that was not solved with what I said earlier and I fixed it doing this:

1. Create a custom menu that runs this:

```
function addOnEditTrigger(){
  var haveTrigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(haveTrigger.length == 1){ return };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('notifyReportedIssue')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

A new user can copy that file, open it, open the menu, run the function and create the needed trigger right there.

---

OLD answer:

Dont use onEdit(e)

Create another function: myFunctionToRunOnEdit(e) and then set a trigger that runs the function onEdit

[image of trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHjQM.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How would you refactor my code so it's using the onEdit in the proper way?

Comment: You just need to call it a different way. Don't call it onEdit(e) because just by naming it like that, google will run it "on edit". Call it functionBlah(e) and then set a trigger that will run the function when there is an "edit" on the spreadsheet.

Comment: I just added an image of the trigger you can setup